# Include version number when compiling shared objects

Tags: c, linux, gcc

This is a more general question. I know windows DLL's can have a resource file set up with the dll version information, but I'm wondering how to do the same for linux shared objects.

The problem I'm encountering is actually when running just about anything at the terminal, I get a message about libz.so.1 version information not being available. This is due to an application being present with its own version of libz that I've compiled. The library is actually libz.so.1.2.3 and the same version exists in /lib. The files are actually the SAME version of the library, but one of them (which I compiled) says it's missing version information.

So, that leads me to wonder how to actually include the version information in the binary rather than just in the file name. It would be ideal if there's a solution like

```
./configure .... some_version_option=1.2.3
```

If I use the working version of the library:

```
ldd /usr/bin/git
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdfbff000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3797fa7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003c56000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c55c00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c55400000)
```

If I use the version I compiled:

```
ldd /usr/bin/git
/usr/bin/git: libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/git)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff872b1000)
libz.so.1 (0x00007f83c9270000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003c56000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c55c00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c55400000)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you see? What is the output of command `ldd ./application` where the aplication is any program which gives you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the library's symbol version map file with `-Wl,--version-script <file.map>`.  The map file should be included in the library source.

Comment: Thanks! I have to run for now, but I'll recompile tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: SOOOO appreciated. You answered the general question (which I hope will help others too) AND led me to diff version of the zlib source for versions 1.2.3.x. ./configure for 1.2.3 didn't include zlib.map for linux systems, but 1.2.3.x did.